# Can we use set theory (first-order logic) to interpret generic programming in programming languages such as C++?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, programming

As is widely accepted, modern C++ is difficult for beginner engineers, especially for its features in generic programming. I am also an engineer using C++ in industry. I felt it difficult to understand documents here and there. Luckily, I understand FOL and set theory at a certain level and I believe it is elegant and useful to organize features in a language or across languages using some formal system. Unfortunately, I don't understand lambda calculus in detail. As an engineer with traditional math background, I learned FOL from understanding ZFC set theory and this is why I have been using FOL to explain C++, rather than a system from TCS. In fact, I can use FOL to explain C++ to some degree, but I am not sure if FOL is so powerful as to explain all features of generic programming in C++.

For example, here is a simple c++ template declaration:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
private:
    T mem_var;
public:
    template <typename S>
    T func(const S& var)
    {
        return some_operation(mem_var, var); // assume that some_operation returns T
    }
};
```

It is my understanding that we get two statements after declaring this class template. First, for each class (set) $T$, there uniquely exists some class $x$ whose name is `MyClass` and for any $y \in x$, there is some variable $z$ whose name is `mem_var` and $z$ is a member of $y$. With this statement, we can introduce a function symbol MyClass (and a new first-order system) such that each MyClass(T) is a solid symbol. Second, for each class $T$, for each class $S$, there exists a unique function $f$ whose name is `func` and for any $x \in $ MyClass(T), for any $y \in S$, $P([f(x)](y))$, where $P$ is a predicate that indicates the result of an action $f$ conducted by a subject $x$ using data $y$ (note the philosophy of object-oriented programming indicated here).

Is FOL adequate for interpreting all features of generic programming in C++? In fact, I am also assuming that state machine has to be used to update the system so that status update of objects may be considered.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at the [proof assistant's stack exchange](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/), since giving programming languages formal semantics is a common application of proof assistants. FWIW, I think this question itself is on topic both here and there (and possibly in other places like the CS stack exchange).

Comment: You are sort of both asking if C++ features can be written in FOL, and if they can be written in the way you describe mapping sets to classes.  And also implicitly asking if anything useful can be proven.

Comment: One immediate question is *how are you are defining C++*? C++ has several ISO specifications, but those are written in natural language. It also has several implementations, most of which are written in C++. To the best of my knowledge, no version of C++ itself has a formal spec, but parts of it like its memory model might.